# iOS Retina display: images double size

Tags: iphone, ios, retina-display

For testing not/retina display I've created an UIView with size 100x100.

I've create 2 images:
- normal size (100x100)
- retina size (200x200)

I have two situations:
1) Non-Retina display + Normal Size image in background
2) Retina display + Retina Size image in background

The 1st scenario is ok.
In the 2nd scenario the image is double size and in my UIView I can see only 1/4 of the total image.

The same happens when I try to assign a background image to my UIViewController navigation bar as following:

```
if (IS_RETINA()) {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMG_NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND_RETINA] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
else {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMG_NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's a much easier way to do this. Give the retina version of the image the same name as the non-retina version, except with a "@2x" at the end. For example, if your regular image was named `foo.png`, then the retina version should be named `foo@2x.png`.

Then, just refer to the regular version of the filename (e.g., `foo.png`) at all times. When your app is running on non-retina hardware the regular image will be used, but whenever you're on retina hardware the higher-resolution image will be used automatically. It's easier than having to write an if statement for every image you use, plus it'll actually work.

Comment: To clarify, the OP's problem is that his "retina" image is still being created with a scale of `1`, so it's going to be blurry and only show the upper-left quadrant.

Comment: @KevinBallard huh? I'm afraid I have no idea what you're saying. @user915829 yes, whether it's IB or code, just refer to `foo.png` and `foo@2x.png` will get used instead automatically on retina devices.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to code the IS_RETINA test, just add the @2x suffix to the name of the file containing the image you want to use for the retina display, and iOS will automagically use that in preference.

Bundle 2 image files, prettyNavBarBackground.png and prettyNavBarBackground@2x.png

```
#define IMG_NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND prettyNavBarBackground
```

Then you can just use this single call, and iOS will select the appropriate option

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMG_NAVIGATION_BAR_BACKGROUND] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: The @2x automatism works with code too or only when assigning the image with IB?

Comment: @user915829: With code too - just try it out. You have to include all variations of foo.png and foo@2x.png in your project. But in code you refer only to foo.png - everything else happens automatically.

Comment: Yep, code or IB - for each image, iOS will use the best it can find.

Answer (score 0):

U don't have to write any sought of code to distinguish between retina and normal hardware. U just need to add a "@2x" image . This will work fine as perfect.

U don't have to call these images individually, but just write the filename.