# Handling different iphone screen sizes/resolution for background images

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimage, iphone-5, screen-size

I would like to better understand the iphone resolutions etc.

I have an application that has a basic buttonView and logoView. I have output the height of the logoView which will auto fit in height depending on screen size.

For the iphone5 I have 318 to work with.
For the iphone4(<) I have 230 to work with.

My question is, how should I handle the image used for the background of this view. Would I create one three separate images for the following?
-iphone3 etc (230)
-iphone4 retina (230 size, @2)
-iphone5 retina (328 size, @2)

Or would I create only the 2x 230 images, and can I stretch the image to 318 when an iphone5 is used and more space is available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all depends on your image:

- If your Image can be stretched, UIImageView will do all the work.
- If only a part of you image should be stretched you should use this:

  - `imageView.image = [imageView.image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)];`
- If your image can't be stretched you should then do different images for the phones and change them in runtime.

**UPDATE**

For the last point you could do something like this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
BOOL isIPhone = [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone;
BOOL isIPhone5 = isIPhone && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height > 480.0);
if (isIPhone5) {
   imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone4image.png"];
} else {
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone5image.png"];
}
```

Comment: A Perfect answer, could you add additional information on your last point and how to accomplish this please?

Comment: You may also be able to add different images resolutions by appending @2x to the image filenames as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368106/ios-retina-display-images-double-size

Comment: Please change the image name, I think you have mistaken it, and another thing I want to ask, how we handle >iPhone6 by the above way?

Answer (score 7):

iOS 8 has different size classes for different screens. It's explained very well here. Every iOS Developer should go through this [link](https://medium.com/@getaaron/ios-8-development-tips-for-iphone-6-and-iwatch-1c772554ffe0):

Comment: This question was initially asked in '13. When size classes were probably only just been thought about. But thanks for adding this info to an old question for newcomers ;)

Comment: Yes I 've seen that but this question has massive increment in it's value due to 6 n 6+

Comment: That's why I've posted this in old question

Comment: Very important point and this answer should definitely be upvoted so newcomers notice it

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make this a little more succinct you can account for longer screen sizes with a macro.

```
#define ASSET_BY_SCREEN_HEIGHT(regular, longScreen) (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 480.0) ? regular : longScreen)
```

Example usage:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.splashScreenImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:ASSET_BY_SCREEN_HEIGHT(@"Default", @"Default-568h")];
}
```